# Custom ElementType empty getSource criteria?

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype, sources

I'm trying to add a source on a custom element type that shows entries with an empty `assigned_user_id` field. This criteria is not honored and returns the same results as the "All Entries" source. Is there any way to specify a null or empty string criteria value?

```
public function getSources($context = null)
{
    $sources = [
        '*' => [
            'label' => Craft::t('All Entries'),
            'defaultSort' => [
                'test_plugin.dateCreated',
                'desc'
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $sources[] = ['heading' => 'Assignments'];

    $sources['unassigned'] = [
        'label'    => Craft::t('Unassigned'),
        'criteria' => ['assigned_user_id' => '']
    ];

    return $sources;
}
```

Comment: Is your `assigned_user_id` a Craft relation or just a simple integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it to `':empty:'`, as mentioned in the [`DbHelper::parseParam()`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/2.6.3000/src/helpers/DbHelper.php#L447) documentation.